# Trying to understand this polymorphism exercise

Tags: java

In the book, they are trying to create their own arrayList Class using an array object, using polymorphism.

I understand what the code is doing but it will not allow it to compile because their is no dog or cat class.
I have each of them in seperate files.

**error: animal cannot be resolved to a type**

```
public class MyAnimalList {
    private Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
    private int nextIndex = 0;

    public void add(Animal a ) {
        if (nextIndex < animals.length) {
            animals[nextIndex] = a;
            System.out.println("Animal added at " + nextIndex);
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }

}

//next snippet

public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList():
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: after creating an animal class, I am no longer getting the error "animal cannot be resolved to a type", now I am trying to figure out how to make the type of animal, accept the "add"  method.

Comment: The book did not include a class of animal or dog or cat in the example, but it is assumed that dog and cat are obviously animals, and should extend from the animal class.Thanks for any help, just trying to figure out how this all fits together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the whole concept of Polymorphism is Objects can be categorized into more generic objects.

For example: Dogs are Animals, Cats are Animals, and Animals are Living Things

So Polymorphism allows you to define a bunch of generic characteristics(i.e. fields and methods) for one class(Animal) so that all other classes that are categorized under that class(Cats, Dogs, ect) can extend those characteristics.

Now the reason your code is not working is because you have not defined the class Dog or Cat in order to do that you need to first create a class animal that has certain attributes as such:

```
public class Animal{
    //some fields

    //constructor

    //methods
}
```

and then create two other classes Dog and Cat that extend that (extend is a key word meaning that this object is in the category of)

so you would then create:

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    //some fields

    //constructor

    //methods
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    //some fields

    //constructor

    //methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you a modern IDE (e.g. eclipse) ? or are you doing it from command line ?

** If you are NOT using an IDE, I strongly suggest you to do so at the beginning. It will help you go smoother and faster pace. **

If you are using command line tools to write your programs, take a close look at [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Specially **-cp** parameter

You have to provide a folder where java can find compiled class files, that's what -cp is used for. For your case, java seems not to be able to find other .class files (Animal, or Dog etc).

**Polymorphism Concept**

Dog, Fish and a Bird are all animals. So they all inherit some basic concepts. For example all of them move. However a dog runs, a fish swims and a bird flies. Let me show you how it is done in OO:

```
abstract class Animal{
 move();
}


class Dog extends Animal{
   private run(){
     ...
     // implementation
     ...
   }

   public move(){
      run();
   }
}


class Bird extends Animal{
   private fly(){
     ...
     implementation
   }

   public move(){
      fly();
   }
}


class Fish extends Animal{
   private swim(){
     ...
     implementation
   }

   public move(){
      swim();
   }
}


I hope it makes sense =]
```

**PS: Above code is pseudo code, Not Java**

Answer (score 0):

1) an public animal class must be created

2) both a dog and a cat sub-class must be created, both must extend animal. Extending from animal will allow both dog and cat to accept the "add" method.